# The role of the history of participation in interest making, and possible new interest making

Tags: experience, memory

I would like to ask, how much of a role does personalization (e g. some product reminds you of something you did, thought, in the past, or of a relationship you had in the past), play, on code acceptance, and, interest, in the code.

Is it possible that if something is completely novel, it will not, be, purchased, viwed.

Does that mean that someone will disvalue something, if it is not something they experienced in kindergarten (in, in which case, teachers are the true interest makers).

Does this also mean that if I cannot participate (this, is true for everyone), making my own ideas and creations, areas of interest, then I cannot, be, and, become, a future interest maker?

Thank you for addressing this issue.

Comment: Note, my post is related to user experience, because, products in software development and outcomes, and their outcomes, is related in some way to past experiences (and new experiences).

Comment: So my post here is about how much the past and the new weigh in UX, and whether new ideas really exist.